# NestJs - Catching MongoDB errors with a custom filter and @Catch(MongoError)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, nestjs

I'm using NestJS to create a custom API with MongoDB. I've got the following setup:

```
  // users.controller.ts

  @Post('sign-up')
  @UseFilters(MongoExceptionFilter)
  async signUp(@Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<any> {
    return await this.userService.signUp(createUserDto).catch(error => {
      throw new BadRequestException(error);
    });
  }
```

```
  // user.service.ts

  async signUp(createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<User> {
  const createUser = new this.userModel(createUserDto);
    return await createUser.save();
  }
```

```
  // mongo-exception.filter.ts

  import { ArgumentsHost,Catch, ConflictException, ExceptionFilter } from '@nestjs/common';
  import { MongoError } from 'mongodb';

  @Catch(MongoError)
  export class MongoExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
    catch(exception: MongoError, host: ArgumentsHost) {
      console.log('>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> exception: ', exception);
    }
  }
```

```
  // package.json
  "dependencies": {
    "@nestjs/common": "^5.4.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^5.4.0",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^0.2.1",
    "@nestjs/mongoose": "^5.2.2",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^5.1.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^5.2.2",
    "fancy-log": "^1.3.3",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.7",
    "nestjs-config": "^1.3.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-http-bearer": "^1.0.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.12",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.2",
    "typeorm": "^0.2.12",
    "typescript": "^3.0.1",
    "util": "^0.11.1"
  },
```

Now whenever I do a POST call to the /sign-up route, `save()` should be called in the `user.service.ts`. This all works. Next when I POST the /sign-up route another time it should trigger a MongoDB error since the user with the same email address is already (email address is unique and thus duplicate keys). I see the error is thrown when I just log the error in the `.catch(err => ...);`, but the problem is the custom `MongoExceptionFilter`. I won't trigger on the MongoError. When I leave the `@Catch()` blank it does trigger but can't process the exception.

What am I doing wrong? Since I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50864001/how-to-handle-mongoose-error-with-nestjs) post and used this as a foundation I can't seem to get it to work. Is it an update of Mongoose or NestJS why this isn't working anymore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because you convert all errors to `BadRequestExceptions` so that your `MongoExceptionFilter` will not be responsible; it checks `instanceof MongoError` which returns false for a `BadRequestException`:

```
return await this.userService.signUp(createUserDto).catch(error => {
      throw new BadRequestException(error);
    });
```

This happens before the exception filters are run; they always run last.

---

Remove `.catch()` from your controller. If you really want to transform all other exceptions to BadRequestExceptions (400), then you can write a second exception filter, that processes all exceptions not handled by the MongoExceptionFilter:

```
@Catch()
export class BadRequestFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: Error, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const response = host.switchToHttp().getResponse();
    response.status(400).json({message: exception.message});
  }
}
```

and

```
@Catch(MongoError)
export class MongoFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: MongoError, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const response = host.switchToHttp().getResponse();
    if (exception.code === 11000) {
      response.status(400).json({ message: 'User already exists.' });
    } else {
      response.status(500).json({ message: 'Internal error.' });
    }
  }
}
```

Then add both to your controller (order is important!):

```
@UseFilters(BadRequestFilter, MongoFilter)
async signUp(@Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto): Promise<any> {
```

Comment: Can you give me some more context? So you mean the .catch shouldnt be there? Can you post an example of what you mean?

Comment: Yes, you can just remove the `.catch`. The catch transforms any error from your `signUp` method into a `BadRequestException`. The transformation happens before your `MongoExceptionFilter` gets called with the error. Since it is now a `BadRequestException` and not a `MongoError` any more, the `MongoExceptionFilter` won't handle it. Instead of transforming an internal error to an exception that is understandable for the client (e.g. 404) in the controller, do exactly that in your exception filter.

Comment: This is because you cannot throw exceptions in an exception filter, you have to create the response directly. I've added an example to my answer.