# How can I handle TypeORM error in NestJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I'd like to create a custom exception filter that handles different kinds of TypeORM errors. I've looked up the [TypeORM error classes](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/tree/master/src/error), and it seems like there's no such thing in TypeORM like [MongoError](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/core/api/MongoError.html).

I wanted to make something similar to [1FpGLLjZSZMx6k's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51617106/3252438), and here's what I've done so far.

```js
import { QueryFailedError } from 'typeorm';

@Catch(QueryFailedError)
export class QueryFailedExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: QueryFailedError, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const context = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = context.getResponse<Response>();
    const request = context.getRequest<Request>();
    const { url } = request;
    const { name } = exception;
    const errorResponse = {
      path: url,
      timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
      message: name,
    };

    response.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).json(errorResponse);
  }
}
```

If I need to catch another error for instance, `EntityNotFoundError`, I have to write the same code which is a very cumbersome task to do it.

It would be nice if I could handle errors by a single filter like below. Any ideas?

```js
@Catch(TypeORMError)
export class EntityNotFoundExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: MongoError, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    switch (exception.code) {
      case some error code:
        // handle error
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In the [documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#exception-filters-1), it says:

> The `@Catch()` decorator may take a single parameter, **or a
>   comma-separated list**. This lets you set up the filter for several
>   types of exceptions at once.

So in your case you could write:

```
@Catch(QueryFailedError, EntityNotFoundError)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. So how am I supposed to handle different exceptions? What would be the first parameter in catch() method?

Comment: @JeffMinsungKim As they all extend `Error` the type can either be `Error` or an explicit list of the types `QueryFailedError | EntityNotFoundError`. If you have code specific to certain errors, you can guard this logic with `instanceof`.

Answer (score 23):

To handle different kinds of TypeOrm errors, you can switch / case the exception constructor if it matches any TypeOrm error (from node_modules\typeorm\error). Additionally, the (exception as any).code will provide the actual database error that occured. Notice the @catch() decorator is empty in order to catch all error types.

```
import { ArgumentsHost, Catch, ExceptionFilter, HttpException, HttpStatus, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Request, Response } from 'express';
import { QueryFailedError, EntityNotFoundError, CannotCreateEntityIdMapError } from 'typeorm';
import { GlobalResponseError } from './global.response.error';

@Catch()
export class GlobalExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
    catch(exception: unknown, host: ArgumentsHost) {
        const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
        const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
        const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();
        let message = (exception as any).message.message;
        let code = 'HttpException';

        Logger.error(message, (exception as any).stack, `${request.method} ${request.url}`);

        let status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR;
        
        switch (exception.constructor) {
            case HttpException:
                status = (exception as HttpException).getStatus();
                break;
            case QueryFailedError:  // this is a TypeOrm error
                status = HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY
                message = (exception as QueryFailedError).message;
                code = (exception as any).code;
                break;
            case EntityNotFoundError:  // this is another TypeOrm error
                status = HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY
                message = (exception as EntityNotFoundError).message;
                code = (exception as any).code;
                break;
            case CannotCreateEntityIdMapError: // and another
                status = HttpStatus.UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY
                message = (exception as CannotCreateEntityIdMapError).message;
                code = (exception as any).code;
                break;
            default:
                status = HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
        }

        response.status(status).json(GlobalResponseError(status, message, code, request));
    }
}


import { Request } from 'express';
import { IResponseError } from './response.error.interface';

export const GlobalResponseError: (statusCode: number, message: string, code: string, request: Request) => IResponseError = (
    statusCode: number,
    message: string,
    code: string,
    request: Request
): IResponseError => {
    return {
        statusCode: statusCode,
        message,
        code,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        path: request.url,
        method: request.method
    };
};


export interface IResponseError {
    statusCode: number;
    message: string;
    code: string;
    timestamp: string;
    path: string;
    method: string;
}
```

*Note: As of new version of `typeorm` import for `EntityNotFoundError` and `CannotCreateEntityIdMapError` will be as bellow*

```
import { QueryFailedError } from 'typeorm';
import { EntityNotFoundError } from 'typeorm/error/EntityNotFoundError';
import { CannotCreateEntityIdMapError } from 'typeorm/error/CannotCreateEntityIdMapError';
```

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive example. I used it as a template for NestJS error handling on my project.

Comment: Very useful answer! However, I'm wondering if it is secure to return the database exception to the user. Isn't it bad if potential attackers can obtain table names, foreign keys, etc. by purposely throwing exceptions?

Comment: How can I use it in my code?

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { ArgumentsHost, Catch, ExceptionFilter } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeORMError } from 'typeorm';
import { ErrorMessage } from '../error.interface';

@Catch(TypeORMError)
export class TypeOrmFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
    catch(exception: TypeORMError, host: ArgumentsHost) {
        const response = host.switchToHttp().getResponse();
        let message: string = (exception as TypeORMError).message;
        let code: number = (exception as any).code;
        const customResponse: ErrorMessage = {
            status: 500,
            message: 'Something Went Wrong',
            type: 'Internal Server Error',
            errors: [{ code: code, message: message }],
            errorCode: 300,
            timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        };

        response.status(customResponse.status).json(customResponse);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide more details on your solution, not only code.

Comment: Please share, how and where to use this implementation. an answer like this doesn't do any good

Comment: I assume he is still writing it lol

Answer (score 0):

you can make something like this

```
@Catch(TypeORMError)
export class EntityNotFoundExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: TypeORMError, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    const request = ctx.getRequest<Request>();
    let status = exception.getStatus();
    let message = '';
    switch (instanceof exception) {
      case InitializedRelationError:
        // handle error like
        staus = 1;
        message = '2';
        break;
      case AlreadyHasActiveConnectionError:
        // handle other error
        break;
      ...
        // ATTENTION other exception classes from node_modules/typeorm/errors 
      ...
      default:
        // handle it like internal server error
        status = 500;
        message = 'Database exception';
    }
    
    response
      .status(status)
      .json({
        statusCode: status,
        timestamp: new Date().toISOString(),
        path: request.url,
      });
  }
}
```